# ASP.net undo preventDefault()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a page with a submit button (create).

when adding another button (calculate profit), the form submit launches when ever user clicks on it.
so i added preventDefault() when calculate profit button is clicked.
"calculate profit" button has onClick that calls this javascript code:

```
function NetProfit() {
            $('form').submit(function (ev) {
                ev.preventDefault();
            });
            document.getElementById('strRes').innerHTML = "";
            var pdata = new FormData();
            var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: "/ExternalMerch/Product/NetProfitCalc",
                data: { price: price },
                success: function (data) {
                    var str = JSON.stringify(data).split(',');
                    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                        document.getElementById('strRes').innerHTML = document.getElementById('strRes').innerHTML + str[i].replace('"', '').replace('"', '').replace(']', '').replace('[', '') + '</br>';
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {

                }
            });
        }
```

Now it works fine when i click calculate profit,
but when user is done filling the page details and click create, the page wont submit.
i know it is because of the preventDefault from when clicking calculate profit.
is there a way to undo this and launch form submit when clicking on create?
[image]

Comment: Where and how did you add the `preventDefault()`? Can you share the code from the cshtml?

Comment: added the javascript in the main thread, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to submit form when clicking Create button,you can try to set `type="button"` in Calculate Profit button,and remove `$('form').submit(function (ev) {ev.preventDefault();});` in function `NetProfit`.Here is a demo:

View:

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Product Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Calculate Profit" onclick="NetProfit()" />
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Available Quantity</label>
        <input class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

js:

```
function NetProfit() {
            alert("Calculate Profit");
        }
```

result:
[image]